# How to map every element of a spark dataframe with its respective column name and apply few transformations on that using scala?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have ORC data like this (uploaded as image)

[ORC data when loaded into dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzmt4.png)

There is no schema defined for the content in the rows, so I want to break this into `RDD's` and move into another `Dataframe` which has some defined schema (using the "`structType`") so that I can read the JSON.

So when I tried breaking these things into RDD's by just selecting the columns - I am getting like below

```
[{"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : { "c1": 3, "c2" :4}},{"d" : 5, "e" : 6, "f" : { "f1": 7, "f2" :8}},{"g" : 9, "h" : 10, "i" : { "i1": 11, "i2" :12}}]
[{"a" : 13, "b" : 14, "c" : { "c1": 15, "c2" :16}},{"d" : 17, "e" : 18, "f" : { "f1": 19, "f2" :20}}​,{"g" : 21, "h" : 22, "i" : { "i1": 23, "i2" :24}}​]
```

I want to transform this RDD like below to put in my Dataframe which has schema defined

```
{"Column 1":{"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : { "c1": 3, "c2" :4}},"Column 2":{"d" : 5, "e" : 6, "f" : { "f1": 7, "f2" :8}},"column 3" :{"g": 9, "h" : 10, "i" : { "i1": 11, "i2" :12}}}
{"Column 1":{"a" : 13, "b" : 14, "c" : { "c1": 15, "c2" :16}},"Column 2":{"d" : 17, "e" : 18, "f" : { "f1": 19, "f2" :20}}​,"column 3":{"g" : 21, "h" : 22, "i" : { "i1": 23, "i2" :24}}​}
```

All I need is mapping the every element in a row with its respective column name and adding `" "` to those column names and wrapping the entire row in `{}`

I can't `split` on `"},"` as the JSON's might have nested structure till 2 levels and could be anywhere in JSON. ​

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way you can convert your dataframe to json:

```
df.toJSON
  .map(_.replace("\\", "")
        .replace("}\"", "}")
        .replace("\"{", "{"))
```

I am using regex to strip unwanted charatcters. Note that this might not be very performant in case you have many records.